# Subsonic 3 and Scaffold

Tags: subsonic, scaffolding

In Subsonic 2 I played around with the Scaffold controls to build some quick and dirty admin pages.  I need to do the same again but am using Subsonic 3 where I don't see Scaffold anywhere.

Is Scaffolding in Subsonic dead?

Any other recommendations to get admin pages for db tables (ms sql) up as fast as possible using Subsonic?